# Error running Python apps in Ubuntu

Tags: python

This is the first time I've tried Python.  I followed this [guide](https://github.com/8planes/mirosubs), and want make this app running in Ubtuntu 10 server.

I used `easy_install virtualenv` and followed the rest of the setup steps.  But, I got errors in step 8:

```
(mirosubs-env)root@makserver:/usr/local/src/mirosubs# python manage.py syncdb
Error: No module named sorl.thumbnail
(mirosubs-env)root@makserver:/usr/local/src/mirosubs# ./dev-runserver.sh
Error: No module named south
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What errors did you get with the previous steps?

Comment: Re your comment to Nick Bastin: You need to do `easy_install django`.

Comment: @Vinay Thank for your install command it works, I finished the rest required modules which name is pretty obvious for using easy_install to get. But I got this error `raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError haystack: cannot import name Thumbnail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like either you forgot to install some additional Python modules or your documentation doesn't mention them.  You need to do:

```
sudo easy_install South
sudo easy_install sorl-thumbnail
```

Of course, you may encounter further problems, but that should solve your immediate issue.

Comment: You are right. after install South and sorl-thumbnail I got another import error: no module named django.core.managment. and sudo easy_install django-core-management that name I came up with doesn't work

Comment: @yozly: It seems like you're trying to install a Django app, but haven't actually installed Django - you're probably going to have a lot more problems than just this since you probably also don't have a database, schema setup, users, etc.  You really need to find some INSTALL documentation for your application.  (You can install Django with apt-get, or possibly easy_install, but that'll just be the start of a bunch of new problems if you don't find a setup guide)

Comment: I know it's pretty annoying to solve this endless problems, But I solve the rest module requirement problem by it's name, I can't find the setup guide right now. Thank you very much. BTW if you can help me chick the error code in below this question comment(It's not the same problem as the last one)